# Increase value of a text box while click on corresponding button in same row ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to ionic and angular. I have created a form with ng-repeat as shown. I have a text box and a button for each text box. I want to increase value of the text box while click on corresponding button near text box.

```
<ion-list id="allitems" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
<ion-item>
<form id="form1">
<div class="row">
<input type="text" id="nos_{{ $index }}"  name="nos_{{ $index }}" ng-model="data.myitem.nos" > 
<button class="button button-assertive button-small button-outline icon ion-ios-minus" id="allitems-button10" ng-click="increment_nos($index)">        
</button>
</div>
</form>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

My controller function is as follows

```
.controller('allitemsctrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$timeout','$window', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, $timeout,$window) {   
$scope.items = [{'id': '1', 'item_name': 'abc'}, {'id': '2', 'item_name': 'xyz'}, {'id': '3','item_name': 'pqr'}];
var data = {};
$scope.data = {};             
$scope.increment_nos = function (index) {
//I want to increase value of nos while click on corresponding button near nos textbox                    
}             
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first link a separate value to each text box

```
ng-model="items[$index].nos"
```

and after that, in the controller increment that value like this:

```
$scope.increment_nos = function (index) {
    items[index].nos = items[index].nos + 1;
}
```

but first set a initial values to `nos` to 0